# Strange weka side effect

Tags: scala, machine-learning, nlp, weka, side-effects

I have a weka classifier successfully working (in scala).
I'm trying to implement a second classifier to work alongside it.

During training, I'm setting up the instances for the first classifier like so:

```
val data = new Instances("Actions",attrs,10)
```

This works fine. Simply adding the following line, however, breaks the program.

```
val tagdata = new Instances("Tags",tagattrs,10)
```

When this line is added, the program crashes *when the first classifier is updated*
Literally the only change between working and nonworking is the addition to that line. Tagdata is never used (everything using it has been commented out, for those who read my last question), and the program doesn't even crash on the added line. This makes it seem like there's some weird side effect to creating this second set of instances. Can classifiers not be trained side by side?

Here's the error it throws:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 75
at weka.estimators.DiscreteEstimator.addValue(DiscreteEstimator.java:89)
at weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes.updateClassifier(NaiveBayes.java:322)
at Parser$.addInstance$1(Parser.scala:253)
...
```

and here's a working subsample (so long as you have weka.jar in ./lib/, and a conll format testing file in ./resources/). Uncommenting the `val tagdata...` line will yield the mentioned problem.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.File
import scala.util.Random
import weka.core._
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesUpdateable
import java.net.URL

object Parser{
  //TypeDefs
  type Arc = (Int, String) //Index, Label
  type Tag = (String, Double) //Tag, probability
  type Token = (Int, String, Int, String) //Index, Word, Head, Label
  //Running params
  val testing = true
  var training = true
  var parsing = true
  val testFile = "test.conll"
  val chooser = new wekaChooser()
  //Data structs
  val storedTokens = MutableList[Token]()
  val buffer = Queue[Token]()
  var stack = Stack[Token]()
  val arcs = HashMap[Int, Arc]()
  val tags = HashMap[Int, String]()
  val classifier = new NaiveBayesUpdateable()
  val tagclassifier = new NaiveBayesUpdateable()
  val tagFrequencies = HashMap[String, List[Tag]]()
  val supplementalTagFrequencies = Map("eat" -> List(("VB", 1.0)), "beans" ->     List(("NN", 1.0)))
  val contextLists = Map("unknown" -> List(), "confirmation" -> List(("UH", 0.8), "right",     "correct", "right", "yes"))
  val context = ListBuffer[Tag]()
  val attrs = new FastVector(4)
  val tagattrs = new FastVector(4)
  var counter = 1

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    if(training) train(testFile)
  }

  def resetLists()={
    buffer.clear
    stack.clear
    stack.push((0, "ROOT", 0, "ROOT"))
    arcs.clear  
    storedTokens.clear
  }

  def applyAction(action:String, buffer:Queue[Token], stack:Stack[Token]):Unit= {
    action match{    
    case "QUIT" => {
      println("Could not parse :(")
      buffer.clear
      stack.clear
    }
    case "SHIFT" => {
      stack.push(buffer.front)
      buffer.dequeue
    }
    case "REDUCE" => {
     // tags.put(stack.top._1, 
       storedTokens += stack.pop
    }
    case x =>{
      x.split("~")match{
        case Array(action, label) => 
          if(action=="LEFTARC"){
            arcs.put(stack.top._1, (buffer.front._1, label))
            storedTokens += stack.pop
          }
          if(action=="RIGHTARC"){
            arcs.put(buffer.front._1, (stack.top._1, label))
            applyAction("SHIFT", buffer, stack)
          }}}}
      }

def train(testFile:String)={
  var wordsmap = HashMap[Int, String]()

def leftDependents(tokenindex:Int) = {
  arcs.filter(_._2._1==tokenindex).filterKeys(_<tokenindex).keys.toList
}

def addInstance(action:String)={
 val data = new Instances("Actions",attrs,10)
//     val tagdata = new Instances("Tags",tagattrs,10)
 data.setClassIndex(2)
 //tagdata.setClassIndex(2)
 val instance = new Instance(3)
//     val taginstance = new Instance(3)
 instance.setDataset(data)     
 //taginstance.setDataset(tagdata)     

 val wordshead = wordsmap.size match{
   case 0 => "NIL"
   case _ => {
     wordsmap(buffer.front._1)
   }
 }

 List(stack.top._2, buffer.front._2, action).zipWithIndex.foreach{
   case (attrString:String, index)=> attrs.elementAt(index) match{
     case attr:Attribute => {
       instance.setValue(attr,attrString)
        }
     }         
   }

 println(instance)
  //   println(taginstance)

//     tagclassifier.updateClassifier(taginstance)
 classifier.updateClassifier(instance)
 }

def setupClassifier = {
 val acts = List("LEFTARC~", "RIGHTARC~")  
 val List(words:List[String], cpostags:List[String], deprels:List[String]) =   Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("resources/"+testFile)).getLines.toList.map{
   line => line.split("\t") match{
     case Array(id, word, _, cpostag, _, _, head, deprel, _, _) => (word, cpostag, deprel)
     case _ => ("","","")
   }
 }.unzip3.productIterator.toList.map{
   case x:List[String] => (x.toSet++Set("ROOT", "NIL")).toList
   case _ => List()
 }

 val classWords = new FastVector(words.length)
 for(word <- words) classWords.addElement(word)
 val classTags = new FastVector(cpostags.length)
 for(tag <- cpostags) classTags.addElement(tag)

 val stacktag = new Attribute("stacktag", classTags)
 val buffertag = new Attribute("buffertag", classTags)
 val wordattr = new Attribute("word", classWords)

 val fvaction = new FastVector(deprels.length*2+2)
 fvaction.addElement("SHIFT")
 fvaction.addElement("REDUCE")
 for(act <- acts; deprel <- deprels) fvaction.addElement(act+deprel)     
 val action = new Attribute("action", fvaction)

 attrs.addElement(stacktag)
 attrs.addElement(buffertag)
 attrs.addElement(action)     

 tagattrs.addElement(stacktag)
 tagattrs.addElement(wordattr)
 tagattrs.addElement(buffertag)

 val structure =  new Instances("Actions", attrs, 10)
 structure.setClassIndex(2)
 classifier.buildClassifier(structure)

 val tagstructure =  new Instances("Tags", tagattrs, 10)
 tagstructure.setClassIndex(2)
 tagclassifier.buildClassifier(tagstructure)
 }    
//The Code
println("training")
//Based on Malt's oracle prediction training. Assisted in finding that by Rehj.
val wordtaglist = HashMap[String, ListBuffer[String]]()
resetLists
setupClassifier    
Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("resources/"+testFile)).getLines.foreach{
 line =>{
   if(!line.isEmpty)
     line.split("\t") match{
       case Array(id, word, _, cpostag, _, _, head, deprel, _, _) =>{
         wordtaglist.getOrElseUpdate(word, ListBuffer[String]())+=cpostag //update tag counts
         buffer+=((id.toInt, cpostag, head.toInt, deprel))
         wordsmap+=(id.toInt -> word)
         while(buffer.nonEmpty){
           val action = {
             if(!(stack.top._1==0) && (stack.top._3 == buffer.front._1))
               "LEFTARC~"+stack.top._4
             else if(buffer.front._3 == stack.top._1)
               "RIGHTARC~"+buffer.front._4
             else if(leftDependents(buffer.front._1).nonEmpty && leftDependents(buffer.front._1)(0) < stack.top._1)
               "REDUCE"
             else if(buffer.front._3 < stack.top._1) //&& buffer.front._3 is not root or handling roots normally
               "REDUCE"
             else "SHIFT"
           }
           addInstance(action)
           applyAction(action, buffer, stack)
         }
       }
       case _ => println("line didn't match")
     }else {
       resetLists
       wordsmap.clear
     }
 }
}
resetLists
tagFrequencies++=wordtaglist.map{ case(k,v) => (k, v.groupBy(x=>x).map(x=>((x._1,  x._2.length*1.0/v.length))).toList)}
training = false
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal compilable example for this? It's very difficult for people to debug when we can't get it running.

Comment: Also, feel free to slap me for anything I'm doing that's terrible Scala. Still learning it! :)